# Change Liquid comment code in Sublime text

Tags: shopify, comments, liquid, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using the Liquid plugin in Sublime Text 4 and when I try to comment out a line of text it does a normal html comment like `<!-- -->` when I'm really expecting a Liquid comment like `{% comment %} {% endcomment %}`.

The liquid plugin seems like it's more about coloring the text than actually doing anything useful like using the correct syntax. How can I change this to use the correct comment structure?

Comment: The comments that are used by the `toggle_comment` command are based on the scope at the cursor, but also require metadata to be defined (by syntax authors) that tells Sublime what the comments are supposed to look like. What package are you using to get this syntax?

Comment: Sublime text liquid extension is mainly used for syntax and autocomplete purposes, they can't support the default comment shortcut using the keys. you need to use autocomplete and try to write comments and append, but it doesn't work with keyboard shortcuts yet.

Comment: I'm using the regular (only?) Liquid plugin that works in Sublime 4. The plugins in VSCode work with the correct syntax but it's never worked in Sublime and I hate VSCode and don't want to use it. The Sublime text extension doesn't even do syntax auto complete. It only formats the colors. Would it have anything to do with syntax defs? https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html#meta_patterns